# assertion 'GTK_IS_LABEL (label)' failed when calling gtk_label_set_text() outside the function it created

Tags: c, label, gtk3

## Back ground

I'm creating something an information board GUI which shows a string changing with **GTK+3 Label widget.

For scaffolding, a simple code with **gtk_label_set_text** is running well as follow:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static GtkWidget* label;

static void
activate (GtkApplication *app,
          gpointer        user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *button;
  GtkWidget *button_box;

  window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Window");
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 100, 20);

  label = gtk_label_new (NULL);
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), label);
  gtk_label_set_text (GTK_LABEL(label), "kerokero");

  gtk_widget_show_all (window);
}

int
main (int    argc,
      char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;

  app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);  
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
    
  
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}
```

The result is as expected with the label whose text is **kerokero** as follow:

[image]

## problem

I've moved the **gtk_label_set_text** function from **activate callback** to **main** function as follow:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static GtkWidget* label;

static void
activate (GtkApplication *app,
          gpointer        user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *button;
  GtkWidget *button_box;

  window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Window");
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 100, 20);

  label = gtk_label_new (NULL);
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), label);

  gtk_widget_show_all (window);
}

int
main (int    argc,
      char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;

  app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);  
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  gtk_label_set_text (GTK_LABEL(label), "kerokero");    
  
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}
```

The **gtk_label_set_text** occurs an assertion failure as follow:

```
(process:17078): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 11:24:55.839: gtk_label_set_text: assertion 'GTK_IS_LABEL (label)' failed
```

and the label string is not changed to "kerokero"

[image]

## Question

How can I change the string of labels dynamically outside the activate callback? Or, should I find another Widget for this purpose?

Comment: I never worked with GTK but my guess is that at the moment when you try to set the label the app activate signal did not fire yet so label is not created.

Comment: Aha! I'll try to put a sleep.

Comment: Hi blami, you are so clever!
It' fixed with 1 sec sleep! Thx!

Comment: You should not use a delay to do this. Why would you? You just must ensure you are doing it after `activate` was called which is when you call `g_application_run`. Do whatever you need inside of `activate` directly or in any callback to other events where you need it.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Why don't you set the text already when you create the label? If you want to change text based on some other signal lateron, you won't need such strange delays but just do it.

Comment: Thank you blami, I agree you.
What I would like to do is as [follow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75877505/application-get-100-cpu-after-first-fireing-of-gtk3-g-io-add-watch-of-a-named).