# Application get 100% CPU after first fireing of GTK3 g_io_add_watch() of a named pipe

Tags: c, gtk3, named-pipes

I'm making the following application which watches a **named pipe** named "info" and update label text with the provided string by this named pipe.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

GtkWidget* label;

static void
activate (GtkApplication *app,
          gpointer        user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window;

  window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Window");
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 100, 20);

  // create label
  label = gtk_label_new ("aho");
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), label);


  gtk_widget_show_all (window);
}

gboolean my_callback(GIOChannel *source, GIOCondition condition, gpointer data){
  gchar *buf=NULL;
  GError *error = NULL;

  g_io_channel_read_line(source, &buf, NULL, NULL, NULL);
  gtk_label_set_text (GTK_LABEL(label), buf); 
  g_free(buf);

  // for next watch
  g_io_add_watch(source, G_IO_IN,(GIOFunc) my_callback, NULL);

  return FALSE;
}

int
main (int    argc,
      char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  GIOChannel *channel;
  int status, fd;

  app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);  
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);

  channel = g_io_channel_new_file ("info", "r", NULL);
  g_io_add_watch(channel, G_IO_IN,(GIOFunc) my_callback, NULL);

  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}
```

This application worked well except that **CPU occupation gets 100%** after **first firing of g_io_add_watch()** when a string was written to the named pipe from an outer process fx: `echo neko > info`.

I've checked my profile but there is no information.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/gtk3-sandbox $ gprof ./infobox3 gmon.out
Flat profile:

Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
 no time accumulated

  %   cumulative   self              self     total           
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  Ts/call  Ts/call  name    

 %         the percentage of the total running time of the
time       program used by this function.

cumulative a running sum of the number of seconds accounted
 seconds   for by this function and those listed above it.

 self      the number of seconds accounted for by this
seconds    function alone.  This is the major sort for this
           listing.

calls      the number of times this function was invoked, if
           this function is profiled, else blank.

 self      the average number of milliseconds spent in this
ms/call    function per call, if this function is profiled,
       else blank.

 total     the average number of milliseconds spent in this
ms/call    function and its descendents per call, if this
       function is profiled, else blank.

name       the name of the function.  This is the minor sort
           for this listing. The index shows the location of
       the function in the gprof listing. If the index is
       in parenthesis it shows where it would appear in
       the gprof listing if it were to be printed.
```

What is the cause of this 100% CPU? How can I avoid it?
How can I achieve to fined the cause and solution?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're getting 100% CPU is because the pipe got closed with a HUP signal after the process was done with it. As a consequence, every time your app checks for new data, it immediately returns with `G_IO_HUP`. At that point, the corresponding `GIOChannel` can't be used anymore.

The way to fix this is by explicitly adding `G_IO_HUP` in your `g_io_add_watch` call and checking for it in your callback. If you want to read again from the same file, you'll have to create a new `GIOChannel` and add that with `g_io_add_watch()` instead.

In any case, in reality it doesn't make much sense to use `g_io_add_watch()` with `G_IO_IN` while leaving out `G_IO_HUP` or `G_IO_ERR` since you're otherwise explicitly not dealing with any errors (leading to problems like yours).